# Como dar permissões automaticas em shell script

Tags: shell

Tenho um projeto que sempre que subo para produção ou troco de máquina de desenvolvimento eu copio e colo a pasta inteira, só que sempre que eu faço isso eu tenho que dar permissões nessa pasta e em algumas sub-pastas.
Gostaria de criar um `script` para fazer isso automaticamente, alguém sabe me ajudar.

Cenário: Eu copio a pasta `projeto` para dentro do meu `/var/www` dai dou permissões para esse projeto.

```
sudo chmod 755 /var/www/projeto -R
# dai me pede a senha de root, eu digito e ok
# dai eu tenho que alterar outras permissões de outras pastas para escrita
sudo chmod 777 /var/www/projeto/uploads -R
sudo chmod 777 /var/www/projeto/logs -R
```

Imagino ser simples, mas não tenho muita ideia, pois estou pensando na chamada desse shell passar o caminho do projeto onde irá dar essas permissões e não sei se é correto eu passar no dentro a senha de root.

Acho que seria algo assim correto:

```
#!/bin/sh
#dar permissoes necessarias
PASTAPROJETO=$1
sudo chmod 755 '$PASTAPROJETO' -R
sudo chmod 777 '$PASTAPROJETO'/uploads -R
sudo chmod 777 '$PASTAPROJETO'/logs -R
```

Comment: Qual o problema, não está funcionando?

Comment: @alacerda ainda não... nem conhecia todos esses parametros... vou dar uma olhada

Comment: @alacerda infelizmente não... aparentemente quando eu dei o comando ele até rodou sem erros mas não deu certo.

Comment: @Ricardo o script estava dando um erro que não encontrava a pasta. Dai tirei as aspas e funcionou. Mas quando faço a chamada do script eu tenho que passar a senha de root. Isso pq eu coloquei o sudo no script. Terai algo mais simples do que ter que fazer assim? Valew

Comment: @MarceloDiniz cara, você deveria dar permissões ao usuário que está utilizando.

Comment: O problema que vc deveria investigar é como dar permissão a um usuário para rodar certos comandos com o `sudo` sem precisar entrar senha. Isso é perfeitamente possível, mas é uma outra questão. :)

Comment: O Daniel está correto... dar a permissão , você já sabe pois já colocou a resposta na própria pergunta. A questão, pelo meu entender então é a necessidade de rodar isso com root, sem senha através de `sudo`. Escreva o script com os comandos chmod/chown e então rode o script com sudo : `sudo sh meuscript.sh` e ele fará tudo de uma vez. Se precisar evitar a digitação de senha, pesquise sobre a configuração `sudoers` ou faça outra pergunta mais especifica de como utiliza-lo.

Answer (score 4):

use a opção "-p", desta forma estará copiando não só os arquivos e pastas, mas também suas devidas permissões; para entender melhor: $ man cp

Comment: ok, só não entendi o motivo da parte de copiar, sendo que eu estou vendo sobre dar permissões.

Comment: @MarceloDiniz A idéia da resposta é que você pode criar um modelo vazio de projeto, feito de pastas mesmo, setar as permissoes certas nesse modelo. Quando precisar, basta copiar a estrutura toda usando o comando `cp` com o parâmetro -p, pois a cópia terá as mesmas permissões do modelo original, e você não terá que setar permissão nenhuma de novo.

Answer (score 2):

Alternativa a opção `-p` na resposta do @asfelix é utilizar o comando `rsync` para copia.

O rsync faz a copia e mantem o owner, grupo, permissões e datas dos arquivos iguais ao original (com a opção `-a`) . A vantagem em sua utilização é que se os arquivos já existirem ele verifica e corrige estes dados se necessário.

Seria algo como :

```
sudo rsync -a --delete  /diretorio/projeto /var/www/projeto
```

Só toma cuidado para não colocar a barra "/" no final do caminho do projeto, pois isso muda o comportamento do rsync, faz com que ele leia/grave o contúdo, item a item ao invés de fazer toda a pasta.

Parametros uteis no rsync :

```
-n / --dry-run  : não efetiva copia, apenas simula
-i  : exibe arquivo a arquivo e qual atualização está sendo feita
-h  : modo "human-readable"
-v  : modo verbose....
```